# Mockito test - reason of failing my testcase

Tags: java, junit4, mockito

Learnt JUnit yesterday, learning Mockito today

I wrote a simple class;

```
public class FileOperations {
    public boolean autoMove(){
        List<byte[]> patterns = getListofPatterns();
        for(byte[] pattern: patterns){
            System.out.println(new String(pattern));
            if(seekInHeader(pattern)){
                //logic to move file of specific folder of specific extension
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean seekInHeader(byte[] pattern){
        return false;
    }
        
    public List<byte[]> getListofPatterns(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

And trying to test it as follows

```
@Test
public void autoMoveTest(){
    FileOperations fo = mock(FileOperations.class);//stub
    List<byte[]> dummyPatterns = new ArrayList<byte[]>();//specify stub value
    dummyPatterns.add("amit".getBytes());
    
    when(fo.getListofPatterns()).thenReturn(dummyPatterns);
    when(fo.seekInHeader(anyString().getBytes())).thenReturn(true);
    
    System.out.println(new String(fo.getListofPatterns().get(0)));
    System.out.println(fo.seekInHeader("amit".getBytes()));
    System.out.println(fo.autoMove());
    assertTrue(fo.autoMove());
}
```

Output:

> amit
>
> true
>
> false

As I set seekHeader() to return true. Why fo.autoMove() is returning false?

Comment: Also this line is incorrect `when(fo.seekInHeader(anyString().getBytes())).thenReturn(true);`, don't use matchers this way `anyString().getBytes()` ⇐ **WRONG !**. As arrays are special objects use instead `any(byte[].class)`. _Current matchers don't perform type checks, but it is expected to change in version 2.0.0._

Comment: right @Brice, Actually I was not aware with what Mockito gives me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using spy as follows;

```
@Test
    public void autoMoveTest(){
        FileOperations fo = new  FileOperations("");
        FileOperations spyFo = spy(fo);

        List<byte[]> dummyPatterns = new ArrayList<byte[]>();//specify stub value
        dummyPatterns.add("amit".getBytes());

        when(spyFo.getListofPatterns()).thenReturn(dummyPatterns);
        when(spyFo.seekInHeader(anyString().getBytes())).thenReturn(true);//stubbing a method

        assertTrue(spyFo.autoMove());
    }
```

**Why your code is failing**

Because you were not stubbing `fo.autoMove()`. When you call a real method with mocked object, actual method never runs. It just returns default value of return-type or stubbed value. So even if you return `true` from `autoMove()`, it will return false for a mock object.

Answer (score 3):

With a mock, none of the methods actually do anything, unless you explicitly specify that they should.  The whole point of a mock is that the functionality has been replaced, either by no functionality at all (the default), or by functionality that you stub.

The default functionality for a mock is that **every method** does **nothing** at all, then returns either `false` (for booleans), zero (for numeric primitives), an empty collection, or `null`.  So in this case, `autoMove` will always return `false`, unless you stub it to do something different.

The whole idea of using mocks is that you ***don't mock*** the class that ***you're trying to test***.  Instead, you mock other classes that it interacts with.  So if a method of class `A` calls a method of class `B`, and you wish to test class `A`; then you would use a mock of class `B`, and stub the method of `B` that gets called.

Comment: +1 As a pedantic point, you could use a spy to achieve what he is trying to achieve, but the point is that he is trying to achieve the wrong thing.

Comment: I'll find the solution hwile learning Mockito further. However, now I got an idea where I was wrong.